# C# report builder pdf too wide

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2013, report, builder

Work in VS2013 and using the report builder with C#.
Report works fine.
Exports beautifully to Word.
But when I send it to a .pdf, it renders very w i d e.

Any you report gurus know the secret sauce on this to get a .pdf to render "better". It's a simple text report, one table, no graphics, nothing fancy...

Answer (score 0):

Find out what font is used in the report. (Press Ctrl+D in Adobe Reader.) Then, use some tool to embed that font. Alternatively, in Report Builder, see if you can change the font.